# Partitioning table on year and week of the year

Tags: vertica

I am trying to `ALTER` a table but its giving below error:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME partition by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_timestamp(CC)); 

ROLLBACK 2552:  Cannot use meta function or non-deterministic function in PARTITION BY expression 

alter table TABLE_NAME partition by date_part('YEAR',to_timestamp(CC)); 

ROLLBACK 2552:  Cannot use meta function or non-deterministic function in PARTITION BY expression
```

Data in CC column is like

```
1441650600
```

EPOCH time

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: can you please give some more detailed info like what you are trying to alter?

Comment: [Have you looked at any of the Google search results?](http://bit.ly/1QGipxh)

Answer (score 0):

As you know Vertica classifies function based on their behaviour as volatile, stable and immutable. More details [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/SQLFunctions.htm).

Now, as you can check in the Administrator's Guide [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/PartitioningRepartitioningAndReorganizingTables.htm)  `PARTITION BY` clause expressions can only use **immutable** functions while TO_TIMESTAMP() - as you can check [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TO_TIMESTAMP.htm?Highlight=to_timestamp) - is only "stable".

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find making these types of alterations easier by doing the following: 
1. creating a new temporary table (with the changes that are to be made) that mirrors the table I want to alter
2. Then I copy all of the data over to the new table
3. Delete the original table 
4. Rename the new table to the existing name.

This the one aspect of the version control we use where I work, everything is stored in Delta scripts so all of the changes to my code is fully documented.

As far as creating projections using an alter statement I cant really comment however I do have a script that I feel would work for you because I am using a similar data format to yours. The column is called DateKey and the format is YYYYMMDD00:

```
2014020100
```

I want to partition by year and quarter so I have written the following

```
CREATE TABLE Schema1.fct_Table1 (
DateKey INT NOT NULL,
col1 INT NOT NULL,
col2 INT NOT NULL,
col3 INT NOT NULL,
col4 INT NOT NULL,
col5 INT NOT NULL
)
ORDER BY DateKey, col1, col2, col3
PARTITION BY left(cast(DateKey as char(10)),4) 
        || case 
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) in ('01','02','03') then '01' 
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) in ('04','05','06') then '02' 
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) in ('07','08','09') then '03' 
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) in ('10','11','12') then '04'  end;
```

So my script is partitioning by the year and the the quarter for that year, 
I.e. 
months 1 - 3 are Qtr 1
months 4 - 6 are qtr 2 etc.

I guess you could write something like:

```
PARTITION BY case 
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) = '01' then '01'
        when substring(cast(DateKey as char(10)),5,2) = '02' then '02'
```

etc.